# what does ${PATH:+$PATH:} mean in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I am checking a bash script which contains something like: export PATH=${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/bin
I assume it has same output as `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`. I did a `echo ${PATH:+$PATH:}` it just output the value of $PATH plus a ':'. but if I modify it to  ${PSOMETHING:+$PATH:}, it outputs nothing.

my question what's the different between using $PATH: and ${PATH:+$PATH:}? any benefit? how to understand the syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See **Parameter Expansion** in `man bash`:

> ```
> ${parameter:+word}
> ```
>
> Use  Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, other-
>         wise the expansion of word is substituted.

Comment: I just found it on http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html thanks anyways